# Load the data from CSV using NumPy and perform operations based on the data type of each column

Tags: csv, numpy

I am trying to load the data from CSV file using NumPy (don't want to use pandas) using CSV.reader(). The file is comma delimited with different data type fields.
I have 3 datatypes int, str, float. I am facing 2 issues:

1. ) Load the CSV file in NumPy array with correct data types.
2. ) Use operations on each column like == and <= based on the type as str or int/float. For e.g. if the column.dtype is "str" then search if BoB is present in this column and retrieve all the rows.

Comment: Show your coding attempt and where you have problems.  See the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` with `dtype=None` (with optonal `names`parameter) should give you a `structured` array with the correct `dtype` for each field.  Remember that's named fields, not numbered columns.